# Access field of parent object(Opportunity) from child object(Quote) through a flow

Tags: visual-workflow

Two Objects Opportunity(Parent) and Quote(Child). I want to have a Custom button on the quote object that calls a flow And in that flow i want to access StageName field of the opportunity object.
How should i do it?
please Help
Efforts will be appreciated
Thank you

Comment: Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/384955/edit) your question to add what Flow you have built so far (it's OK if it fails) and how it is not working (e.g., *exact* error text, unexpected results). This site exists to *help*, not do the work. (From the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of Help Center: *"We’re not a place to exchange code or find implementation services."*)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Get Records](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_data_get.htm&type=5) element to get the Opportunity with the desired field, then you can access the field, such as `{!Get_Opportunity.StageName}`.